# How can I filter a list based on whether it contains any of a list of substrings?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a list of Japanese words. I want to produce a formula to filter that list, based on a filter list of substrings (kanji characters) which I'm looking for.

So for example, say my filter list contains three characters, 水 and 木 and 日. I want to find every word in my list which contains 水 or 木 or 日. That's an inclusive or - any words which contain more than one of the characters on the filter list (such as 木曜日 or 水曜日) should show up, too.

[image]

So far, my formula works with just one character to filter for:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$44492, "SELECT A WHERE A LIKE '%"&A2&"%'")
```

However, I've tried expanding it to a range, and it doesn't work:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$44492, "SELECT A WHERE A LIKE '%"&A2:A4&"%'")
```

It only filters words containing the first character, 水.

Is there a way to filter the whole list based on all the items in my list? And to be clear, I want it to be dynamic, so that I can put in as many filter characters as I like to the list, rather than basing it on an exact number of filter characters.

Comment: Have you tried the query or the updated answer following your comment? Did any work for you?

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos, I asked this question on stackoverflow separately and received an [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58457458/1907765) using a Regex, which solved my follow-up question. Thanks for your help in answering this question as well!

Comment: It is interesting that you chose the `FILTER` solution *(which needs an additional helper column)* over your original `QUERY` one. Also, regarding the answer in stackoverflow, it is on a diferrent site as well as just a part of the whole formula. Not the answer to it. In any case, glad it all worked well.

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos, I only needed the part rather than the whole, as the `REGEXMATCH` solution worked fine for my purposes even with a helper column. Thanks for your assistance, but I'm happy with the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter function with `REGEXMATCH` as a parameter, try this in `C1` :

```
=FILTER(B2:B100,arrayformula(REGEXMATCH(B2:B100,TEXTJOIN("|",true,A2:A4))))
```

It filter the range `B2:B100` based on which result returns the regex

---

**Explanation** :
The following formula returns `False` or `True` based on the content in the cells `B2:B100`. The operator `|` is basically a `OR` in this regex.

```
=arrayformula(Regexmatch ( range , "水|木|日" ))
```

**Breakdown** : 
[image]

[Live demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/107L7pctN71Wis0bBUbCSieBbyQliLVebXEk4Xk4257M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I don't suppose you know how I could modify it if I wanted to make words which *only* contain those characters pop up? And none others?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your original QUERY function.
You just have to change `like` to `matches` along with the `TEXTJOIN` function.
**It is `matches` that allows you to use a regular expression (regex) in the `QUERY` function**.

```
=QUERY(B14:B,"select B where B matches '.*["& TEXTJOIN(,true,A14:A16) &"].*'")
```

> **UPDATE**
>   *following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135591/how-can-i-filter-a-list-based-on-whether-it-contains-any-of-a-list-of-substrings/135619#comment124164_135609):
>
>   ...**make words which only contain those characters pop up and none others***

You only change the regular expression included in the query:

```
=QUERY(B14:B,"select B where B matches '^(?:(["&TEXTJOIN(,true,A14:A16)&"]))+$'")
```

Comment: Following your comment. Please check the updated answer.